# multidomain, multilanguage, keep indicization, multiheadache

Tags: i18n-l10n, domain-access

I am trying to figure out how to migrate a website with multidomain and multilanguage settings, keeping SERPs.

PREFACE:
I have 17 website all identical, except language, in pure html. All 17 website got good SERP positions...
site.com
site.de
site.fr
site.ch
site.co.uk
site.pt
site.ca
...

PROBLEM:

I have installed drupal, create the template and fill up the CMS with all content necessary. I have used the i18n module to translate the website. Basically I have one node for each content.

node/1 ABOUT US 
node/2 QUI SOMMES NOUS
node/3 CHI SIAMO 
node/4 QUIENES SOMOS

They are linked so when I click on the languageflag the content change based on the languauge:
site.com/fr/qui-somme-nous.html
site.com/en/about-us.html
site.com/es/quienes-somos.html
site.com/it/chi-siamo.html

The old web pages are structured like this:

site.fr/qui-somme-nous.html
site.co.uk/about-us.html
site.es/quienes-somos.html
site.it/chi-siamo.html

and now the source of enormous headache...

How can i set up drupal in order to got on the same drupal installation the different topdomain and different multilanguage content, keeping the search engine position?

Hoping to have enough explain my situation.

Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to would be to build this with [domain access](https://www.drupal.org/project/domain) use a different domain for each language to meet your criteria. Repoint the old urls to the new ones.

Another way would be by indicating the language in the url.  Read more about it here: http://indico.cern.ch/event/216222/contribution/10/attachments/345315/481614/multilingual-training.pdf Start at page 37.

Probably a few other ways.

Comment: thank you Gary, this is what I was looking for.  great documentation as well